# Difficulty understanding result of RijndaelManaged encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

After reading many questions and answers on SO, I'm yet to figure out why the code I've written below is producing unexpected results.  I used the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class to produce a 128-Bit Key for use with the `RijndaelManaged` class.  I generate the IV using `GenerateIV()`.  Am I doing something wrong here?  Many of the code examples I've looked at are pretty much exactly this.

```
string text = "TEXT TO ENCRYPT";
string key = "MY_KEY";
byte[] saltRaw = BitConverter.GetBytes((long)text.Length);
Rfc2898DeriveBytes deriver = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, saltRaw);
byte[] keyRaw = deriver.GetBytes(32);

RijndaelManaged rij = new RijndaelManaged();
rij.Key = keyRaw;
rij.GenerateIV();

ICryptoTransform encryptor = rij.CreateEncryptor(rij.Key, rij.IV);
MemoryStream sMemory = new MemoryStream();
CryptoStream sCrypt = new CryptoStream(sMemory, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(sCrypt);
sWriter.Write(text);
byte[] r = sMemory.ToArray();

sWriter.Dispose();
sCrypt.Dispose();
sMemory.Dispose();
encryptor.Dispose();
return r; // length of r is 0.
```

The problem here is that the `byte[] r` has a length of 0, so nothing was written to the memory stream.  CryptoStream doesn't implement the `length` property so I can't check to see if anything was written to it.  I'm also aware that I don't preprend the Salt or the IV to the result, I'm yet to do this.

Comment: I thing you are missing padding options

Comment: I haven't seen a single `RijndaelManaged` example that includes information regarding padding.  Can you expand further?

Comment: Can whoever downvoted please explain their downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing solely your zero-length `r` issue, this is due to buffering within the `StreamWriter`, so at the point you attempt to get the contents of the `MemoryStream`, nothing has actually been written to it.

```
byte[] r;
using (var sMemory = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var sCrypt = new CryptoStream(sMemory, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        using (var sWriter = new StreamWriter(sCrypt))
        {
            sWriter.Write(text);
        }
    }
    r = sMemory.ToArray();
}
```

I strongly suggest that you use `using()` blocks as above, rather than explicitly calling `Dispose()` as this will ensure proper disposal even in case of exceptions, and also helps avoid use of objects after they are disposed, or forgetting to call `Dispose()` at all.

Even assuming the code works as expected following the change above, there are various other security issues in the code which are beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it.  I should have realised this was the problem, much appreciated.  Would you mind briefly detailing the other security flaws?